# Blender 2.9) How to unhide background image when press shift H?

Tags: interface

When I press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>H</kbd> to hide all objects except selected one, the background image is hidden too.

Is there a way to lock background image from all of actions not only select?

Comment: Why not select your background image + main object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use alt+h to unhide things. In the future you may want to use / which isolates everything you've selected, pressing / again will bring everything else back.